# Flutter about color ib boxdecoration

Tags: flutter, dart

> Cannot provide both a color and a decoration To provide both, use
> "decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color)".
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart': container.dart:1 Failed
> assertion: line 273 pos 15: 'color == null || decoration == null'

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Text(title),
      color: color,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [ 
            color.withOpacity(0.7),
            color,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: That seems to be a very descriptive error message, even telling you what to change. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
  child: Text(title),
  color: color, ***--> Delete this line!***
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: color, ***--> Put that line here!***
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [ 
        color.withOpacity(0.7),
        color,
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have set a `decoration` already, so drop the `color: color,`, because it's not suported to do both.

Answer (score 0):

the error is self explanatory it says that when you are using decoration n the container you have to pass the color inside the decoration like this

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: //color
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [ 
        color.withOpacity(0.7),
        color,
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
  ),
```